# Data is fetched from sqlite db in ios7.1 but not fetched when using ios6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I am using sqlite database to fetch data from db to my app's UITableView.Data is
fetched when using ios7.1 simulator but data is not fetched when running ios6.1 simulator.How to fetch data from db for both os version for same sqlite database.

```
+(BOOL)copyFile{ 
NSString *strSourcePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Db" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSString *strHome=NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *strDestPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/NewDb.sqlite",strHome];
NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *err;
if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:strDestPath]==NO) {
    [manager copyItemAtPath:strSourcePath toPath:strDestPath error:&err];
    return YES;
}
else{
    NSLog(@"file already exists");
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}

+(NSMutableArray*)getDetails{
NSString *strHome = NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *strDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/NewDb.sqlite",strHome];
NSMutableArray *arrDetails=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
sqlite3 *db;
int n = sqlite3_open([strDestPath UTF8String], &db);
if (n==SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *strQuery=@"SELECT * FROM Categories";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *err_msg;

    int res=sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [strQuery UTF8String], -1, &stmt, &err_msg);
    if (res == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            Categories *categories=[[Categories alloc]init];
            categories.categoryId=sqlite3_column_int(stmt,0);
            categories.categoryName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
            categories.categoryImage=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];
            [arrDetails addObject:categories];

        }
    }
}
return arrDetails;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Well, I'd like to confirm it's really hard to support both iOS 6 and 7 for the same app. Do you really need to support previous version?

Comment: yes.my app has to support ios6 and 7

Comment: Okay, seems like you use something which depends on iOS version. How you get the path to SQLite database? It's very common mistake since it differs on following iOS versions. And it would be easier to answer your question if you show the code.

Comment: The sqlite code is the same in iOS6 and iOS7, so the issue isn't with your sqlite code *per se*, it must be some other issue within your app (like not copying the database or something).

Comment: how do i find if database is copied or not